# Unable to extract civicrm zip file in file manager

Tags: wordpress, error, installation

I tried to follow the civicrm install guide for wordpress (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/). I am stuck after copying the civicrm-5.28.0-wordpress.zip file into the file manager under /wp-content/plugins. When i try to un-zip the file i get the following error message:

"Unable to extract files from "WP Root/wp-content/plugins/civicrm-5.28.0-wordpress.zip". Unable to save "civicrm".

I appreciate every suggestion what i might be doing wrong, thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have permission to write into the plugin directory? Can you try extracting into your home directory and move the civicrm folder into plugin directory

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response! I do have permission to write and when i try extracting in my home or another directory in the file manager i encounter the same problem and "unable to extract files from..." error.

Comment: May be try extracting on your laptop or machine?

Comment: Then i get numerous error messages like "Unable to upload .gitnigore". Invalid file name." "Unable to upload .github". Invalid file name." and about 15 more of those. Thank you for your help so far! I hope you have some more ideas what the issue is.

Comment: I think i found the problem! It doesnt work with all the folders or files starting with a dot ".", this seems to be not allowed in the file manager. I will have to find a way around this somehow.